# How to use a created column as argument to ORDER BY with CASE clause in MySQL? (#42S22 error)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I need some help over here.
I'm working with some reports generation using MySQL. One of the columns I created was called TOTALSUM and it was created by an operation using a CASE clause. When I try to use an ORDER BY, it accepts this TOTALSUM, but if I include this inside a IF os CASE clause, it doesn't accept anymore.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN COL1 = 01 THEN COL2 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN COL1 = 03 THEN -COL2 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTALSUM,
```

If I do something like this, it works:

```
ORDER BY TOTALSUM
```

But if I do something like that, it doesn't work, giving the following error: #42S22Reference 'TOTALSUM' not supported (reference to group function)

```
ORDER BY IF(:INPUTVALUE = "X",TOTALSUM,ITEMCODE)
```

Is there anyway to make this work?

Comment: This should work in MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it does not work in versions prior to 8.0

Comment: @forpas is there anyway to do something like this in the prior versions? I need the same result, but the methodology can be different